# Padding in arrayadapter with custom item on dropdown spinner

Tags: android, layout, spinner

I would like to have a dropdown spinner with prompt but I have trouble configuring it. Right now I managed to display the prompt by overriding getItem in my adapter but it is ignoring the padding for some reason.

```
        category = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.category);


        List<String> categoryList = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories));
        categoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, categoryList){


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                if (!firsttime) {
                    firsttime = true;
                    return super.getCount(); // you dont display last item. It is used as hint.
                }
                return super.getCount()-1;
            }

        };
        categoryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);

        category.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

        category.setSelection(categoryAdapter.getCount());
```

spinner in xml:

```
<Spinner
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/category"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                android:paddingTop="5sp"
                android:paddingStart="15sp"
                android:paddingEnd="15sp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/text_selected" />
```

spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_selected"
    android:padding="5sp"
    />
```

String array:

```
 <string-array name="categories">

        <item>For Sale</item>
        <item>Services</item>
        <item>Vehicles</item>
        <item>Property</item>
        <item>Category</item>
    </string-array>
```

Before I select anything, it looks like this (there is no padding):
[image]

when I select something:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your spinner height

```
<Spinner
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp" //like this
                android:id="@+id/category"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                android:paddingTop="5sp"
                android:paddingStart="15sp"
                android:paddingEnd="15sp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/text_selected" />
```

Comment: I might do that at the end.

Answer (score 1):

in your spinner item.xml: you are using `sp` for padding use `dp` instead

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_selected"
    android:padding="6dp"   //change here
    />
```

Comment: There is no change :(

Comment: did u add the dp values in main xml also

Comment: try removing the `style` in spinner tag...see this [Example](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2015/08/android-spinner-text-padding.html)

Comment: I remove the style and didn't see a single change. When I add padding to the relative layout that hosts the spinner, Category is still cut in half.